# Combining 2 columns in MySQL table to create a new stored column with a specific string

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns in my table:

```
month_name    Year   
June          2018    
July          2018    
Aug           2018
```

I want to alter my table and create a new stored column called `month_id` by combining the other 2 above columns into a string of '201806', to create a new column as:

```
month_id
201806
201807
201808
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) with the use of the [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) of MySql:

```
alter table tablename add month_id varchar(6)
generated always as (
  date_format(str_to_date(concat(left(month_name, 3), Year, '01'), '%b%Y%d'), '%Y%m')
) stored;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gq7oYEJ3UeMzhE4rg9nRK3/0).
Results:

```
| month_name | Year | month_id |
| ---------- | ---- | -------- |
| June       | 2018 | 201806   |
| July       | 2018 | 201807   |
| Aug        | 2018 | 201808   |
```